# Need to make .htaccess file show all pages html

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking for .htaccess code that will make all my my pages .html code

example

```
http://domain.com/random

http://domain.com/random/blabla

http://domain.com/ all this pages here make them .html code
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. I'm assuming that all of your pages shown on that .htaccess document are written with HTML... are you saying that you want them to be shown as the raw HTMl on the .htaccess? That's not only impractical but it's also not possible as far as I know. Pleas word your questions more clearly.